# xubuntu in hyper-v freezes keyboard and mouse clicks after some idle time

Tags: hyper-v, xubuntu

Usually I'm using virutalbox, but as there are supposedly some performance issues if one runs virtualbox together with WSL2 I decided to try out Hyper-V.
I have virtually no experience, so perhaps there is something obvious which I'm doing wrong.

I installed Xubuntu 20.04 on hyper-v on a windows 10 machine.
The machine also runs WSL2 though I'm not sure it matters as the problem also shows up if all WSL entities are terminated.

The machine works perfectly in graphical mode and I installed openssh-server and can also connect to the VM.

After some idle time, the graphical interface shows some strange behavior.

I can still see the display.
When I move the mouse cursor over the screen I see (depending on the cursor position) the cursor shape change, but neither mouse clicks nor keyboard presses are handled anymore.

On the other hand connecting via ssh is still working.
When trying to use x11vnc to connec tot he screen I observe exactly the same issue, that
mouse clicks and keyboard presses are ignored, but the cursor is still moving.

I disabled the screen saver as I thought perhaps it creates some strange side effects, but it changed nothing.

**Addendum**
I figured out, I can provoke the same situation much faster.

- I start the VM
- I log in
- I start one window (e.g. a terminal window)
- I use the ctr-alt-del icon on the hyper-V cctrl bar

The VM will immediately fall into the same behavior.

Mouse pointer moves and changes shape whenever being over the border of the terminal window. nothing else possible with kbd / mouse

Also, but I think this is how hyper-v is supposed to work.

I always start hyper-v as administrator. If I don't I can't create virtual machines

**Addendum 20-09-16**:

In fact it seems to be a problem of the windows manager.

If I press ctrl-alt-F1, I can switch to a text console and there all keys are still working. Si it seems to be the windows manager, that because of one or the other reason decides to ignore key presses / mouse clicks. (Perhaps an invisible application grabbing the focus?)

Comment: The mouse for Hyper-V is the host mouse driver. Try updating that. I have a machine here with WSLg preview and Hyper-V both. The mouse (TrackPoint or BlueTooth) works reliably in Hyper-V and WSLg with a Linux Guest machine.

Comment: The PC (a laptop) is rather new (just a few weeks) and normally all drivers are up to date.
I tried to search for updates for mouse and keyboard and found no newer one.

Comment: Maybe try a different mouse.  Otherwise I am not sure.

Comment: What is bizarre and why I didn't consider driver issues is, that the mouse is not completely dead. the cursor is till moving, but clicks are no more handled and and additionally it's not only the mouse that is broken, but also the keyboard

Comment: just found out something new:

I can provoke exactly the same behavior if I send ctrl-alt-del via hyper-V  to the VM 

(mouse buttons / keyboard presses ignored) but mouse cursor still moving

Comment: will try to remove the mouse and just use the touch pad. The mouse is wireless perhaps that's causing some issues

Comment: That is possible. See what happens with the Touch Pad.

Comment: same problem if I unplug the wireless mouse dongle (Did'nt reboot the machine though. but I restarted the VM and hyper v manager

Comment: Bug report on Launchpad: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xfce4-screensaver/+bug/1880124

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned by [@gelonida](https://superuser.com/a/1676501/247361), this issue is likely related to screensaver. For a VM, its a waste to have screensaver enabled so its probably best to uninstall it and block it from being re-installed automatically.

Uninstall:

```
sudo apt remove xfce4-screensaver
```

Block from being re-installed by creating `/etc/apt/preferences.d/noscreensaver.pref` as su with contents:

```
# This is to prevent screensaver from ever being installed
Package: xfce4-screensaver
Pin: release a=*
Pin-Priority: -10
```

Answer (score 2):

In case other people encounter the same issue.

I do not understand why things a re happening, but I found a workaround.

When the display freezes

- I press Ctrl-Alt-F1 (switch from the X-display to a text console)
- I login as the same user as for my X session
- I use ps to identify a process `xfce4-screenssaver`
- I kill this process
- I press alt-F7 to go back to my x-windows screen

Now everything is unlocked again:

Why all this is happening (especially as I **explicitly disabled the screensaver** in settings) is beyond my comprehension

Following article seems to indicate, that disabling Xubuntu screen savers doesn't work properly.
https://www.reddit.com/r/xubuntu/comments/j4tqop/xubuntu_20041_who_is_blanking_my_screen_after_10/

> Fresh install of Xubuntu 20.04.1, ..., no matter how I configure the power management options or the screensaver options, even if I disable both altogether, ... screens blank after exactly 10 minutes if the keyboard and mouse remain idle. I did not see this same behavior in my years long use of 18.04.x. What am I missing here?

I personally don't mind a screensaver, but I'd like to know how to get my mouse and keyboard back (how to end the screen saver)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same freezing problem with Slackware 15 - current xfce and VOID-xfce. Ubuntu was OK, even with xfce4, until I installed Xubuntu-desktop.
Fixed by replacing xfce4-screensaver with xscreensaver in Slackware, disabled xfce4-screensaver autostart in VOID (can't remove it). I just removed xfce4-screensaver in Ubuntu and let the Windows screensaver take over.
No longer freezing - fingers crossed.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).