# xubuntu 20.04 Unable to disable xfce4-screensaver

Tags: screensaver, xubuntu

I posted a question ( [xubuntu in hyper-v freezes keyboard and mouse clicks after some idle time](https://superuser.com/questions/1676430/xubuntu-in-hyper-v-freezes-keyboard-and-mouse-clicks-after-some-idle-time) ) and it finally turned out, that the real reason is following:

I installed XUbuntu 20.04 and disabled the screensaver in the settings. However the screensaver cannot be disabled.

What is the cleanest way to disable the screen saver for one user?

If I want to disable for all users uninstalling xfcce4-screensaver might be a solution.

Following article seems to indicate, that the issue is known, but the solution seems to be to just maximize all the delays or to open a can of worms by installing two screen savers.

https://www.reddit.com/r/xubuntu/comments/j4tqop/xubuntu_20041_who_is_blanking_my_screen_after_10/

> Fresh install of Xubuntu 20.04.1, ..., no matter how I configure the power management options or the screensaver options, even if I disable both altogether, ... screens blank after exactly 10 minutes if the keyboard and mouse remain idle. I did not see this same behavior in my years long use of 18.04.x. What am I missing here?

Comment: I have Xfce but not XUbuntu. I find Screen Saver under Power Manager in All Settings and then Display Power Management to never blank.

Answer (score 0):

Switch to xscreensaver and disable xfce4-screensaver in Session and Startup.

Comment: I don't really understand your answer.

I have problems disabling the screen saver. This is what the question is about.


Perhaps you can elaborate on what you mean with
`disable xfce4-screensaver in Session and Startup`


(what files to modify or which interactive programs to use and where to click)